# String interpolation in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I tried all of this but can't predict interpolation read all points in official [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade) but not yet found elegant solution-

```
{{ url('/posts/' . $post->id . '/comments' }}

{{ url('/posts/$post->id/comments') }}
```

Finally this one worked but I expecting something elegant than this

```
@php
  $url = url('/posts/' . $post->id. '/comments');
@endphp

{{ $url }}
```

Comment: Try the first option, but with a closing `)` before `}}`

Comment: Thanks @AlivetoDie silly mistake lets to big confusion your answer really helped me lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try these:-

```
{{ url('/posts/' . $post->id . '/comments') }} // ) missing
```

Or:-

```
{{ url("/posts/$post->id/comments") }} // double quotes
```

Answer (score 4):

The most elegant way is to use route names.

```
# routes/web.php
Route::get('/posts/{post}/comments', 'PostsController@comments')
        ->where('post', '[0-9]+')
        ->name('post-comments');
```

Then

```
# PostsController.php
use App\Post
...
public function comments(Post $post, Request $request) {
    // use $post object
}
```

And in view

```
{{ route('post-comments', ['post' => $post]) }}
```

Comment: Mr. Shukshin your answer makes me think deep. Its really elegant.